# Convert a key string to a SecretKeys object in tozny/java-aes-crypto

Tags: java, android, encryption, encoding, secret-key

I'm using [java-aes-crypto](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto) for encrypting strings in android. After generating key using this code

```
AesCbcWithIntegrity.SecretKeys keys = AesCbcWithIntegrity.generateKey();
```

and I'm saving it as String(`.toString()`) in a file and after that I'm trying to retrieve it from that file and convert it to the same object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following static method in the `AesCbcWithIntegrity` class ([link](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto/blob/1.1.0/aes-crypto/src/main/java/com/tozny/crypto/android/AesCbcWithIntegrity.java#L98-L125)):

```
/**
 * An aes key derived from a base64 encoded key. This does not generate the
 * key. It's not random or a PBE key.
 *
 * @param keysStr a base64 encoded AES key / hmac key as base64(aesKey) : base64(hmacKey).
 * @return an AES and HMAC key set suitable for other functions.
 */
public static SecretKeys keys(String keysStr) throws InvalidKeyException {...}
```

It properly parses the previously serialized keys into the encryption key and the integrity key.

Comment: I'm the author of this library and I can confirm that this is the correct answer. Use "keyString" to convert a key to a string and "keys" to convert a string to a key. As quantumThinker pointed out, there are dangers to storing the key, and this may or may not be secure, depending on your use case. Also consider using "generateKeyFromPassword" if that might work for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

On going through the link,one can see that you need to use the following code to convert the encrypted String into the desired one.

```
 //Use the constructor to re-create the CipherTextIvMac class from the string:
  CipherTextIvMac cipherTextIvMac = new CipherTextIvMac (cipherTextString);
  String plainText = AesCbcWithIntegrity.decryptString(cipherTextIvMac, **keys**);
```

The **keys** is the same key that was used while encryption.
As you can see, you need to store the key to decrypt it. The link also provides the precaution to store the key

> Once you've generated a random key, you naturally might want to store
>   it. This may work for some use cases, but please be aware that if you
>   store the key in the same place that you store the encrypted data,
>   your solution is not cryptographically sound since the attacker can
>   just get both the key and the encrypted text. Instead, you should use
>   either the Keystore infrastructure or consider generating the key from
>   a passphrase and using that to encrypt the user data.
>
> If despite the above you still want to store the key, you can convert
>   the keys to a string using the included functions and store them in
>   preferences or SQLite.

Comment: `String plainText = AesCbcWithIntegrity.decryptString(cipherTextIvMac, **keys**);` requires `KeyStore` object not String

Comment: When did i say it requires string??. I said it requires the same key object that was used during encryption..

Comment: then it's not my questions answer. I'm storing it as String and I need to decrypt with string key

Comment: then you should rephrase your question.  there is nothing mentioned about the key in your question..!